# celery with mongodb backend error

Tags: mongodb, celery

After I upgraded to the latest version of `mongodb`, my `celery` task launch failed:

```
celery worker --beat --app=my.celerytask.task1:worker -G <config-files> --logfile <log-file>  --pidfile <pid-file>
```

and I am getting following error:

```
[2015 - 07 - 13 11: 16: 10, 029: ERROR / Beat] beat:
Connection error: command SON([('create', u 'messages.broadcast'), ('capped', True), 
('size', 100000.0)]) failed: collection already exists.Trying again in 32.0 seconds...

[2015 - 07 - 13 11: 16: 42, 190: ERROR / MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to mongodb: 
  //x.x.x.x:27017 vo-db: command SON([('create', u'messages.broadcast'),
 ('capped', True), ('size', 100000.0)]) failed: collection already exists.
```